# Strut-and-tie models for concrete corbel cracking

Tags: structural-engineering, concrete

I'm interested in how to perform serviceability limit crack width checks for concrete connections. Common type of connection is a corbel connection, which I'm currently investigating.

I found one [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25623/how-to-perform-sls-check-with-strut-and-tie-method) from earlier regarding the same topic.

The answer to the question was that one can use strut and tie methods for SLS also, using the stresses in the ties (rebar) to estimate crack widths. The same idea is offered by Eurocode 2:

> 7.3.1
> (8) When using strut-and-tie models with the struts oriented according to the compressive
> stress trajectories in the uncracked state, it is possible to use the forces in the ties to obtain the
> corresponding steel stresses to estimate the crack width (see 5.6.4 (2).

This clause directs to 5.6.4:

> (2) Verifications in SLS may also be carried out using strut-and-tie models, e.g. verification of
> steel stresses and crack width control, if approximate compatibility for strut-and-tie models is
> ensured (**in particular the position and direction of important struts should be oriented according
> to linear elasticity theory**)

Couple of questions rise:

- **What is meant by "the position and direction of important struts should be oriented according
  to linear elasticity theory"?** Annex J.3 gives a strut and tie model of a corbel connection: [image]

How, for example in this model could the struts be considered "oriented according to linear elasticity theory"? I have hard time understanding that this whole sentence could mean.

- Part 7.3.4 of EC2 gives a formula for crack widths, using strains in concrete and steel:

$$w_{k}=s_{r,\max} \left(\epsilon_{\mathit{sm}}-\epsilon_{\mathit{cm}}\right)$$

So, I suppose that this expression could be approximated by using only the steel strain, giving a higher crack width and a conservative estimate. But, the formula also requires the maximum crack spacing $s_{r,\max}$. **How could I estimate that in the case of corbel (or anything else non-beam)?**

Thank you.